# iPad MP4 Embed - Possible 'Target' parameter values...?

Tags: ios, object, embed, target, mp4

I have a web page with a number of MP4 video files embeded at thumbnail size into it ready to play - The size is achieved (probably badly) by reducing the embed dimensions in the OBJECT / EMBED code.

On an iPhone, when the PLAY button is pressed on these miniature embeded videos (200x130), the video starts playing over the top of my page in a full size window. When the video ends or the user is DONE the thumbs page is automatically returned / was waiting underneath.

My problem is on an iPad the video starts playing in the miniature window - The player has an option to upscale to a full sized player window but this isn't ideal.

I understand that this happens because I have reduced the width and height settings in the embed, so I am after a way to achieve the same result I get on an iPhone automatically on an iPad - ie. when the PLAY button is pressed the video starts playing over the top of my page in a full sized player...

Is there a parameter within the object / embed to force a full sized player window to start when the 'play button' / thumb is clicked?

I have a 'fix' of linking from a thumb image to a new page holding the full sized OBJECT / player but this requires extra user 'presses' and a back step to go to the original thumbs page, which I'd like to avoid

Does anyone have a set of possible values for the **param name="target" value="myself"** tag as I thought this might be the cure for my problem, however searching for possible values is drawing a blank.

Thanks for your time and help